# Bool(false) on live but working on localhost

Tags: php, boolean

I have this code on localhost and live hosting but always bool(false) bool(false) on live hosting when I fill up the text area of username and password but it adds up to the database of the hosting but no value in it because its false.

When I run it to my localhost its just fine displaying the results of the username, password and the hash value and adds up to the database.

```
<?php

include "db.php";
require "lib/password.php";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {       
                    $username= $_POST['leguser'] ;
                    $password= $_POST['legpass'] ;  
                    $pwhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) ;
                    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
                    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

                    echo var_dump ($username);
                    echo var_dump ($password);
                    echo var_dump ($pwhash);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE fld_username = '$username'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows == true) { 
                         echo "<script>alert('Username already used!');</script>"; }
                    else
                    {                               
        $q = "INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (`fld_username`,`fld_password`) VALUES ('$username','$pwhash')";
            $result = $conn->query($q);
                if ($result) {
                    echo 'success';
                } else {
                    echo 'failure: ' . mysql_error(); 
                }
                    }            

}
```

?>

Thank you for the help in advance, I am just a beginner in this field :)

Comment: Normally, you should first reduce the example code so that it contains the bare minimum. As it stands, parts are missing and others are superfluous. Then, format your code, after all you want others to read it. Here though, you should take another route and use PDO instead. It does things like escaping of strings to avoid SQL injection for you, which reduces the amount of code you have to write and where you could make errors.

Comment: Check the database connection

Comment: database connection is fine and its connected both live and localhost.

Comment: what do you get for doing a var_dump on $_POST instead of your assigned variables?

Comment: i only get Bool(false) = username  Bool(false) = password and the hash value (60 chars) and a success echo that notify me if it is inserted to the database or not.